# Receiving push notifications using phonegap build

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

I am trying for days now to get a basic application with push notification running.

I am using PhoneGap Build (Desktop App) and am testing on a Android Device.
I tried various tutorials but they never seem to work.
Running the following code just gives no reaction at all.

This is my current code:

**config.xml** I added the following lines:

```
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm">
    <param name="SENDER_ID" value="540732047871" />
</plugin>
```

**index.html**

```
<body>  
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "540732047871"
        },
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
        "windows": {} 
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log("registration event");
        document.getElementById("regId").innerHTML = data.registrationId;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log("notification event");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        var cards = document.getElementById("cards");
        var card = '<div class="row">' +
              '<div class="col s12 m6">' +
              '  <div class="card darken-1">' +
              '    <div class="card-content black-text">' +
              '      <span class="card-title black-text">' + data.title + '</span>' +
              '      <p>' + data.message + '</p>' +
              '    </div>' +
              '  </div>' +
              ' </div>' +
              '</div>';
        cards.innerHTML += card;

        push.finish(function () {
            console.log('finish successfully called');
        });
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("push error");
    });
}};
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using code based on the "*github*"-page of the "*phonegap-plugin-push*". Any ideas what I seem to have missed in creating the project?

Answer (score 0):

@Sven,

**Canned Message**
I am blogging this tomorrow, so i don't have to repeat this answer again and again.

You cannot use *Phonegap Desktop App* with *Phonegap Build*.

*Phonegap Desktop App* uses *Phonegap CLI*, so if you want to use *Phonegap Desktop App* you need to stay with *Phonegap CLI*.

If you want to use *Phonegap Build*, then forget what you have done and start over  ***OR***  make [Minor modifications](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/tutorial-html5ui-hide-show/wiki) to move *Phonegap Desktop App* to *Phonegap Build*. To be clear, the difference is minor, but enough to keep tripping you.

Also, you will not be able to use *Phonegap Developer App* as that is meant to work with *Phonegap Desktop App*. You cannot use either CLI or Build with *Developer App*.

FWIW: The documentation is the issue. I've been trying to get Phonegap to fix this. Here is the [report on the issue.](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-docs/issues/137)

Let me know what you want to do.

Jesse

Comment: Oh okay, didn'T read that anywhere. Thanks for that. I will try to get it qorking with PhoneGap Build then. Maybe that fixes the issue. I'll be commenting what I've found.

Comment: @Sven, it is written in the documentation, but not **very well**.